# A chatbot's take on dynamic scoping: it is easier to debug - correct?

Tags: programming-languages, compilers, language-design

I asked the chatbot at you.com, ["what is an advantage of dynamic scoping?"](https://you.com/search?q=What+is+an+advantage+of+dynamic+scoping) and it said the following on the pane titled YouChat. (If you click the link, you will probably see a different reply by YouChat since, apparently, there is some random/live factor in its algorithm).

> One of the main advantages of dynamic scoping is that it is more flexible and convenient than static scoping. Dynamic scoping makes it easier to pass parameters from one subprogram to another and allows for more efficient use of memory, as the same variables can be used across different subprograms. Additionally, dynamic scoping makes it easier to debug code as the scope of a variable is more visible.

The last statement threw me since I would have thought that dynamic scoping makes it harder to debug as compared with lexical scoping rather than easier, is that correct?

Comment: Chatgpt = dunning Kruger on steroids. It can write sentences that sound reasonable but it hasn’t got a clue what it’s talking about.

Comment: We discourage "is this correct?" questions, as they are unlikely to be useful to others in the future.  I hope we won't see a series of questions of the form "a chatbot told me X, is X correct?"  What research have you done?  What have you found so far?  What are your own thoughts?  Why do you trust a chatbot more than your reasoning?

Comment: @D.W. That was just a link to you.com that I thought I needed to use in order to use you.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not correct.

Dynamic scoping is hard to reason about, and therefore hard to debug; because it is hard to reason about, it causes problems for code analysis tools, including optimisers and garbage collectors. If you're thinking about writing a language, implement block-level lexical scoping from the start. Then you won't have to figure out how to shoehorn it into the language later. [Note 1].

Really, this answer shouldn't be necessary. Or, it should only be necessary as a response to a claim from a credible source, perhaps a source so old that the error is understandable. But I fear that if left unanswered, this question will continue to contribute to the soup of misconceptions out of which AI brews its answers.

---

#### Notes

1. See Perl `my` vs. `local`, or JavaScript `var` vs. `let`/`const`. Changing midstream from one scoping model to another one is difficult and leaves you with a huge legacy corpus using the old model which you have to maintain forever -- or until you get tired of supporting ancient versions -- so it is not a decision to be taken lightly. Think about why both of those languages chose to change their scoping model despite the cost. Read up on the concept of ["technical debt"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt)